# Calculating the number of arrangements of writing a word with $2$ letters beside each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So i was given a question asking how many arrangements of letters in MATHEMATICS are there where the letters TH appear together (in this order)?

From a different example they checked the repetitions in the words for each letter then divided by that.

So there are $2$ $M$'s, $2$ $A$'s, $2$ $T$'s, and mathematics is an eleven letter word.

$\frac{11!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot2!}=4989600$

So I assumed this is correct if there was just a general case but my confusion is how do I check the arrangements if the letters $TH$ have to be together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: write the word as

> MA$\mkern1mu\Theta\mkern1mu$EMATICS,

where $\Theta$ represents TH.  Then use the same technique as in your question.

Comment: So $\frac{10!}{2!\cdot2!}=907200$? @David

Comment: i edited it if you can check, should it be 10 instead of 11?

Comment: That's correct now.

Comment: thank you for the help bro